# AndAlso in VB Linq query, doesn't seem to be working

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

The below query fails with Null Reference Exception when there are elements in BOMIDs where MatID property is nothing.
I thought the 'x.MatID isnot Nothing AndAlso' would prevent the x.MatID.Process part of the where from being executed. There are a couple elements in the BOMIDs collection that where MatID is nothing. 
Any thoughts?

```
From x In BOMIDs _
Group Join y As PurchasedProcess In SpecialProcesses _
On x.MatID.PurchasedProcess Equals y.Name _
Into G = Group _
From z In G.DefaultIfEmpty() _
Where x.MatID IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
x.MatID.Process = ProcessEnum.PurchasedProcess _
Select New With {.Item = x.Item, .Process = z}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AndAlso` isn't the problem. Move your null check to just before the join to effectively filter out all null occurrences before joining on them.

Try this updated query:

```
From x In BOMIDs _
Where x.MatID IsNot Nothing _
Group Join y As PurchasedProcess In SpecialProcesses _
On x.MatID.PurchasedProcess Equals y.Name _
Into G = Group _
From z In G.DefaultIfEmpty() _
Where x.MatID.Process = ProcessEnum.PurchasedProcess _
Select New With {.Item = x.Item, .Process = z}
```

Comment: That works great, thanks. Still getting used to Linq, I think my head is stuck in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

From glancing over your code, it seems that this line might be a potetntial trouble spot as well:

```
On x.MatID.PurchasedProcess Equals y.Name
```

Since `x.MatID` can be `Nothing`